# String format overload not available

Tags: swift

I am trying to format a string with existing variables so that I can display a time, here is the code:

```
func timeString(time:TimeInterval) -> String
{
    let hours = Int(time) / 3600
    let minutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
    let seconds = Int(time) % 60
    return String(format: ”%02i:%02i:%02i”, hours, minutes, seconds)
}
```

However, when I create a new String object, there is no overload to pass a 'format' argument in.

[image]

This, as a result, is giving me three different errors all of which I believe stem from this missing overload.

I must have overlooked something basic (possibly a library I am not importing) but I cannot find anything in the documentation to fix this.

The libraries I am importing are 'UIKit' & 'Foundation'

Comment: `String(format:)` was a bridged method from `NSString(format:)`. It hasn't existed since Swift 3. You should use a proper [`DateIntervalFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateintervalformatter), instead.

Comment: It compiles for me – assuming that you use normal double quotes `"`  and not those typographical quotes.

Comment: @MartinR You godsend, the quotes were not normal double quotes, how foolish of me not to spot it! Thanks!

Comment: @Alexander It's not best practice to use String(format:) anymore?

Comment: In general, `String(format:)` is fine. In this specific case you should use `DateIntervalFormatter` so you can get a properly internationalized result.

Comment: @AlexMarchant No, it was never good practice to hard-code formats for date/currency/etc. related matters. It doesn't localize, unlike the proper `*Formatter` classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness - @MartinR noticed the quotes around the string were not legal double quotes which were causing the issue to arise.

As pointed out by @Alexander, I should use a DateIntervalFormatter because (as explained by @rmaddy) I will get a properly internationalised result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking for, but I thought that using your `timeString(time: )` function to create an initializer for `String` would be a good idea.

```swift
func timeString(time:TimeInterval) -> String {
    let hours = Int(time) / 3600
    let minutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
    let seconds = Int(time) % 60
    return String(format: "%02i:%02i:%02i", hours, minutes, seconds)
}

extension String {
    init (time: TimeInterval) {
        self = timeString(time: time)
    }
}
```

This would allow you to take your `TimeInterval` value (in the following usage example, I am assuming that you already have declared a variable with the `TimeInterval` you want to convert to a `String` called: `timeInterval`)and more easily convert it into a `String`.

```
let timeInterval : TimeInterval = yourTimeInterval

let timeString = String(time: timeInterval)
```

I hope that helps solve your problem!